# Concurrent text file reads by numerous VMs

Tags: java, concurrency, cloud, distributed

I have a java app I am porting as a proof-of-concept to a cloud architecture. I want to process a very large text file by running the same processing program on chunks of the file on separate VMs.

Worker nodes = n

Head node running Master and one Worker, with n-1 Worker nodes

I have two ideas in mind:

1. Master reads file line-by-line, sends first line to first worker node, second to second worker node and so on, repeating every n lines.
2. Master reads number of lines in file. Worker nodes then instructed to read `no_of_lines`/n concurrently from the file.

I am considering using an RMI or sockets based approach for transfer of data. Could anyone tell me which of the above methods would be most efficient? If this question cannot be answered without specifying which java constructs I would be using, I would appreciate suggestions on those.

Also, would locking be an issue with concurrent file access if I each node knows which lines it is supposed to read?

Thanks for any suggestions

Ian

Answer (score 2):

To take the second question first, there is never any problem in many programs reading one file IFF no program is writing the file: each program has its own file-position pointer. Even if some program is writing to the file, there might not be any problem if that program is always writing at the end of the file which, in any sane system, is always the case.

As for the first question, IFF all of the lines in the file are of constant length, then the issue is as always one of efficiency: it's more efficient to read several lines than it is to read one line.

If I were doing the project, the master would ask the workers to read (n_lines_in_file/n_workers) lines. There seems to me little point in the master's reading lines and passing them out to workers. That's assuming, though, that each line takes the same amount of worker processing as any other.

If that's not true, or if there are other variables you haven't told about, my strategy would no doubt change.

Comment: Thanks Pete, the input will be a text file of hundreds of megabytes with the potential for terabytes. I will be starting with a single file on a single machine, but I need to also explore options where the dataset can be created in a distributed way in the first place. I'm looking at SRB at the moment and I may write a program that inputs from a single file, as well as one that reads from a distributed file store. Any thoughts? Cheers

PS. the same queries will be run on each line and is not exactly the same length, but contains the same fields

Answer (score 1):

When you break up a program, you should ensure that you are not creating more overhead than you are looking to save.  For example, reading a few lines of text is relatively cheap compared with doing an RMI call.  Copying the data to many hosts may be more expensive than the processing you intend to do.

How long does the processing take?  This will guide you as to how large each piece of work needs to be to be efficient.  You may find that the optimal number of threads is one. ;)

Comment: Hi Peter, since the file size will be 100s MB -> TBs. Do you think that using RMI calls would create a significant overhead when using them to send large chunks of data to VMs? The bottleneck seems to be I/O when the data are so large, hence I'm thinking SRB/iRODS. Cheers

Comment: You are correct that the IO is likely to be an issue.  This means you want a solution which distributes the data as efficiently as possible and does as little copies as possible. e.g. you could have an RMI call which sends the file name and the region of the file to read rather than the actual data. (Assuming all the serverc an access the data) RMI calls are not free, but if you keep the number of calls low I suspect they won't have much impact.